# Redux state is not updating after adding a blog post

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Okay so I have this React app with a backend built with Node and Express. I got two endpoints, `getAllPosts` and `createPost`. `getAllPosts` returns an array of posts and `createPosts` returns an object with status and message.

So in the frontend I am fetching the data in Redux actions like so:

```
export const getPosts = () => async ( dispatch ) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.get( '/api/posts', config );

        dispatch({
            type: GET_POSTS_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        });

    } catch ( error ) {
        console.log( error ) 
    }
}

export const createPost = ( postData ) => async ( dispatch ) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.post( '/api/post', postData, config );

        dispatch({
            type: CREATE_POST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        });

    } catch ( error ) {
        console.log( error )        
    }
}
```

And the reducers look like this:

```
export const getPostsReducer = ( state = [], action ) => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case GET_POSTS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                posts: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const createPostReducer = ( state = [], action ) => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case CREATE_POST_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                response: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I can successfully render all posts in the first page load but when I create a post, the newly created one is not added right away. If I check the Redux dev tools, I don't see the updated list. But only renders or dev tools show the updated list after I reload the page. .

I am dispatching `getPosts` in one component like so:

```
useEffect( () => {
        dispatch( getPosts() );
}, [ dispatch ] )
```

and dispatching the `createPost` in another component's `submitHandler` like this:

```
const submitHandler = ( e ) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch( createPost( { post } ) );
}
```

I also tried putting the `submitHandler` in the same component where `getPosts` is called so that dispatching it would trigger the `useEffect` and call `getPosts` again to get the updated list. But that doesn't work either. Besides that I also tried adding the returned list  from `getPosts` as dependency in useEffect but if I log it then there are infinite amount gets printed on the log.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A couple of things you can try is removing the curly braces to your createPost function. This way it'd look like this -> dispatch( createPost( post ) ); Then, you may also try adding the ...state, to your reducer return statements so it'll look like this return { ...state,  loading: false,  response: action.payload }; Do the same for both reducers.

Comment: @LeonardoNoronhaSantos I did the second one just now. It isn't updating. I can't remove the curly braces as I'm accepting post in backend as req.body.post. And post is an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that React doesn't know that a new post was created. You'll need to call `getPosts()` after `createPost()` has been called.

```js
const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  dispatch(createPost({ post }));
  dispatch(getPosts());
}
```

If you want to structure your services in a more centralized, scalable way, check out my blog post on React services: https://schneider-lukas.com/blog/react-connect-rest-api. You could just as well store the posts in the Provider component to make them available to all components in the tree, or better yet create a separate Context, Provider, and Consumer for handling posts.

Answer (score 2):

I'd change the structure a bit:

in the createPost method instead of dispatching I'd just return data

```
export const createPost = ( postData ) => async ( dispatch ) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.post( '/api/post', postData, config );

        return data;

    } catch ( error ) {
        console.log( error )        
    }
}
```

and then in your code I'd

```
const submitHandler = ( e ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createPost({post}).then(data=>{
    dispatch({type:CREATE_POST, data})
 }
```

this should definitely work